# iPad 2 Safari not showing progressive .jpg files

Tags: safari, jpeg, ipad-2, progressive

Using iPad 2 with OS 5.1.1. In Safari, trying to display a jpg image through img tag but doesn't shows (shows only ? icon). The same image displays if url directly typed on address bar.

Also noted that if the image saved as non-progressive jpg, it works fine. The progressive jpg saved through photoshop on both "save for web" as well as "save as" methods. Both doesn't helps.

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari has an apparent bug where it won't show some progressive JPEG images if some criteria are met.

In my experience, Safari won't display jpgs when some of the following criteria are met:

- progressive encoding is used
- the image is a background (for an element or the whole page)
- the image is large (I don't know how big exactly, but I ran into problems with images that were in the thousands of pixels wide)
- possibly other things, I haven't fully explored this bug

I have not been able to recreate this in any browser except Safari.

To fix this, you can either re-save the image, making sure that it isn't in a progressive format (photoshop, etc have a selector for this), or use another format (gif, png, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem on iPad simulation and device.
The image can't load as the background but can load via the link.

I fix this by:
 Open this image by photoshop, File -> Save as web, then choose jpeg, save it and replace the old image.