# Background images does not display on iOS only after adding to Home Screen

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

I have a css like this:

```
#thumbnail {
    background-image: url(bla.jpg),
    background-size: cover,
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

It is showing fine on iOS Safari and everywhere else. However, when I "Add to Home Screen" the page, the image will not be shown.

What I tried (with no luck):

1. Using `background-size: contain`
2. Using JavaScript to "lazy load" the background-image.
3. Dynamically appending it as an `<img>` instead of a background-image using JavaScript.
4. Adding it straight into HTML document. It starts displaying but does not obey any CSS style, even after I try it with JavaScript styling, and with `width` and `height` attribute (why?).
5. Using `background-position: top center` instead of `50% 50%`.
6. Using other image format such as `.png`.
7. Applying background-image to `::after` pseudo-element like below:

   ```
   #thumbnail::after {
       content: '';
       display: block;
       padding-top: 100%;
       background-image: url(...),
       background-size: cover,
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: 50% 50%;
   }
   ```

It just doesn't work properly.

I searched StackOverflow and Google for the same problem, none facing the same issue as most of them are referring to problems in Safari browser and non-supported CSS property (which isn't the problem in my case).

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how to solve it?

This problem only occur *after* "Add to Home Screen". It works perfectly fine in iOS Safari browser and iOS Chrome browser.

Comment: Have you checked these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824099/ipad-2-safari-not-showing-progressive-jpg-files

Comment: @LGSon yes I checked but it was 5 years ago and it was only the case in Safari, which is not a problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

This might be like a similar issue I had a while ago.

The only workaround we were able to do is to remove the meta tag for it to be "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" and let users to open it in Safari, where everything seems to work normally.

Comment: that certainly is a way but then it defeats the purpose and experience of adding it to home screen.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `background-image: url(...)` with `background: url(...)`